# Background image change width and height on different sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have an image slider what runs background in my page.  My problem is that images zooms to much on smaller screens. Maybe there is a way how I can change width or height of image so it looks more better and images are not totally zoomed in. As I am not very professional on responsive designs especially on responsive images, maybe someone can give me good advise.

This is how my project looks like.  Screen is taken from HD monitor, but on my laptop its way to much zoomed in and some images are hard to understand.
[image]

CSS what is used for images:

```
.sequence .slide-image > img {
  max-width: inherit;
  display: block;
  /*height:auto;*/
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

HTML part :

```
<div class="slide-image scale">
  <img src="$KBImage" alt="Welcome to the Loyale"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't have a complete example of yours but what about this? https://jsfiddle.net/btd5xh0m/

Comment: Use a vw and vh unit. example: 100vw=current width of window size, 100vh=current heigth of window size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May it help Use a vw and vh unit size:
100 vw = current total window width size.
100 vh = current total window heigth size.

```
.sequence .slide-image > img {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  /*height:auto;*/
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50vw;
  min-height: 50vh;
}
```

Comment: Its a good tip , but it wont work as i wanted to. Now some of images do not cover the whole page.

Comment: I changed min-width and min-height from 50vw to 50% and now it works better.

Comment: if you need image full widht and heigth of windows. may use only  width: 100vw and height: 100vh and remove min and max width/height

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it may help you

```
.sequence .slide-image > img {
  max-width: auto!important;
  display: block;
  /*height:auto;*/
  position: fixed; 
  background-repeat: !important;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
}
```